# Looking up source line numbers from a native crash reported by Google Play

Tags: android-ndk, google-play, callstack, debug-symbols, line-numbers

Google Play reports crashes in my NDK native Android app.
These reports include a callstack.

Good so far, but I would like to know line numbers as well, not just which function it crashed in.

Example report from Google Play:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.steenriver.buggy <<<
backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000001cf97c  /data/app/com.steenriver.buggy-1/lib/arm/libbuggy.so (SoundEngineStart+1500)
  #01  pc 00000000001cc7f8  /data/app/com.steenriver.buggy-1/lib/arm/libbuggy.so
  #02  pc 00000000001e42f8  /data/app/com.steenriver.buggy-1/lib/arm/libbuggy.so (_Z7nfy_msgPKc+120)
  #03  pc 00000000001d657c  /data/app/com.steenriver.buggy-1/lib/arm/libbuggy.so
  #04  pc 00000000001e42f8  /data/app/com.steenriver.buggy-1/lib/arm/libbuggy.so (_Z7nfy_msgPKc+120)
  #05  pc 00000000001c4ae0  /data/app/com.steenriver.buggy-1/lib/arm/libbuggy.so (_Z14view_touchDowniiPiPfS0_+824)
  #06  pc 00000000001465a8  /data/app/com.steenriver.buggy-1/lib/arm/libbuggy.so
  #07  pc 00000000001f3d18  /data/app/com.steenriver.buggy-1/lib/arm/libbuggy.so
  #08  pc 0000000000145b8c  /data/app/com.steenriver.buggy-1/lib/arm/libbuggy.so (android_main+368)
  #09  pc 00000000001f3b84  /data/app/com.steenriver.buggy-1/lib/arm/libbuggy.so
  #10  pc 0000000000046eb3  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
  #11  pc 0000000000019acd  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

I would like to know which line number *SoundEngineStart+1500* maps to.

I did find the [utility ndk-stack](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html) but if I feed it my crash, there are no line numbers shown, and ndk-stack just passes through the crash info as-is.

My NDK binary is build in latest AndroidStudio using cmake external build. I do not use any obfuscation like proguard.

Comment: Did you give ndk-stack the path to a shared library that hasn't been stripped? If you did that and you still can't get it to work, you could try using addr2line directly (e.g. `some-abi-prefix-addr2line -Cfe unstripped-libbuggy.so 001cf97c`

Comment: @Michael That works! If  you write it up I will mark it as the correct answer. In my case, the abi prefix was not req'd btw. Ubuntu's addr2line worked just fine on ARM .so file.